# Duda con función y puntero en C

Tags: c

Buenos días.

Estoy estudiando C con un libro, pero sale el siguiente ejercicio, en el cual he intentado sacandole el `*` a la función `char *str_copy` cambiandolo a `str_copy` nada más. Sin embargo, al intentar usarlo dentro del `printf` me lanza error el compilador.

¿Alguien me puede explicar el por qué del error? entiendo completamente que el valor de retorno es el puntero `t`, que estaría *apuntando* a la string ya copiada con el alias de A.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *str_copy(char *s, const char *p){

    char *t = s;
    while (*s++ = *p++){

    }

    return t;
}

int main(){

    char a[128] = "ABC";
    char b[128];
    puts("Ingrese las letras de b");
    scanf("%s", b);

    printf("A es %s\n", str_copy(a,b));

}
```

Comment: Donde pone `while (*s++ = *p++)` ¿es una errata o está así a propósito? A primera vista veo que podría ser un error (querías poner una comparación `==` pero pusiste por error una asignación `=`), pero quería confirmarlo antes de seguir mirando el código. Por otro lado no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta: ¿a qué te refieres con sacar el `*`? no sé si te refieres a quitar el puntero al valor devuelto o a algún parámetro o a alguna variable. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que funciona y de lo que te falla?

Comment: a proposito! lo que estoy haciendo es copiar los caracteres de la string p (ingresada mediante scanf en el main) uno por uno en la string s(A en el main). Me refiro a sacar el * de la funcion char *str_copy,dejandolo como char str_copy nada mas.Al sacar el * me daba error al usar la funcion dentro del printf.Mil disculpas por la falta de explicacion.

Comment: @OscarGarcia ese bucle está copiando el contenido de `p` en `s` hasta llegar a un caracter nulo. Esta hecho a drede

Comment: Es que si le quitas el `*` lo que devuelve es únicamente un carácter, un valor de 0 a 255 (bueno, realmente de -128 a 127). Supongo que tú quieres devolver una cadena modificada, ¿no?

Comment: @OscarGarcia asi es,esa es la duda que aun no me quedaba muy clara : "El por que del char*"

Comment: Bueno, más o menos ya he "pillado" el sentido del código. @eferion ha editado su respuesta para incluir eso último que te digo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: El `char *` se usa para apuntar a una zona de memoria donde se almacena un valor `char` (un único carácter). Se usa para indicar el primer carácter de una cadena de caracteres (que finaliza generalmente con un `\0`). Si se usa sin el `*` (`char` a secas) estás indicando el valor de un único carácter.

Comment: Aquí encontrarás **mucha** información sobre punteros; hay hasta una etiqueta y todo para facilitarte las búsquedas (`punteros`), y otras relacionadas, como `C` y `C++`. Leyendo las preguntas y respuestas, se aprende mucho. Te lo digo yo, que soy autodidacta también ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *str_copy(char *s, const char *p);

char a[128] = "ABC";
char b[128];
printf("A es %s\n", str_copy(a,b));
```

La función `str_copy` pretende copiar el contenido de `b` en `a` y tu estás esperando que lo haga al revés.

Lo correcto en tu caso sería poner:

```
printf("A es %s\n", str_copy(b,a));
```

En cuanto a lo que comentas del valor de retorno... el tipo `char` hace referencia únicamente a un caracter suelto, mientras que `char*` se usa para cadenas de caracteres.

Si estás intentando algo tal que:

```
char str_copy(char *s, const char *p){

    char *t = s;
    while (*s++ = *p++){

    }

    return t;
}
```

No va a funcionar porque `t` es de tipo `char*`, mientras que el valor de retorno de la función es `char`. Sí que podrías, en cambio, hacer:

```
char str_copy(char *s, const char *p){

    char *t = s;
    while (*s++ = *p++){

    }

    return *t;
}
```

Pero entonces lo único que te va a devolver la función es una copia del primer carácter de la cadena... eso sí, ese carácter no podrías usarlo con el argumento `%s` en `printf`, sino que tendrías que usar `%c`:

```
printf("El primer cacater de B es %c\n", str_copy(b,a));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! es decir,que al querer trabajar con funciones que tengan que ver con string de caracteres debo anunciarlas con char*  en vez de simplemente char?

Comment: Eso es, cada tipo sirve para una cosa diferente. Según mejoren tus conocimientos empezarás a ver el por qué de estos detalles

Comment: Te me adelantaste en la redacción, gracias por tu respuesta, te llevas mi voto :)

Comment: No pasa nada si la pregunta tiene más de una respuesta. Si le das tu enfoque es posible que incluyas información que yo he omitido

Comment: @eferion aun estos pointers me sobrecalientan la cabeza,pero muchas gracias por la explicacion detallada :)